# ExportMenu Kartik PDF File Generation - Too Slow- How to Optimize it?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, pdf-generation, kartik-v

I am using Export Menu from Kartik to generate pdf and excel. I am trying to generate 2000 records with 28 coumns and the file size is around 1mb after being downloaded. I am unable to figure out that why does it take so much time to generate a file of 1mb even though i am using batch sizes and pagination from Active Data Providers in the grid while being fetched from the models. How do i make the file generation quicker like 1-2 seconds?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://demosbs3.krajee.com/export - Used this plugin. 1) Used 'batch' sizes such as 25 to optimize. 2) paginated querying from ActiveDataProvider from Model. for smaller number of records, the ExportMenu generates file real quick like 1 second, but as size increases like 1mb, it takes 6-7 seconds. But for pdf generation, it takes almost a minute. My code is exactly like nothing different than producing columns in the grid view and exporting them through ExportMenu for exporting all data since gridview export only exports page data and All button wasnt that usefull. This is what i have tried

Comment: Edit your comment with more info - `dataprovider` with your relations, `gridColumns` and etc. May be you select many useless data and your sql is slow.

Comment: also try to load your gridview with `$_GET` like `index?per-page=2000` to see how slowly it is. Yes, it's not the same, but you can get the difference between 20 and 2000 rows

Comment: well querying is blazing fast. it takes 300ms to load 3000 records. The issue isnt of querying or SQL....its again, file generation issue on Exporting.

Comment: @vvpanchev yes, you are right, loading 2000 records in gridview is really slow. Thats why i used different method to download/export the data. It doesnt load the grid and then export but rather uses Active Data Provider to get the data and download it

Comment: show code, database structure and so on..